# How split annotated dataset into sentence

Tags: dataset, spacy

i have dataset annoted in spacy 2 format like below

`td = ["Where is Shaka Khan lived.I Live In London.", {"entities": [(9, 19, "FRIENDS"),(32, 37, "JILLA")]}]`

my datasets has sequence length greater than 512 and trying to migrate to hugging face so would like to split document into sentences at same time need to update the tagging also is there any tools available for that my expected result should be like below

`td = [["Where is Shaka Khan lived.", {"entities": [(9, 19, "FRIENDS")]}],["I Live In London.", {"entities": [(10, 16, "JILLA")]}],]`

Answer (score 0):

Why to do it with spacy? write a small parser that split it, and then run spacy on the already split sentences , it will give you the same result you want